# Coefficient are zero using the pylogit conditional logit model

Tags: choice-modeling, mlogit

Trying to understand conditional logic model using the dataset
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pranavn91/PDF/main/xlstats_cbca.csv
But I am getting all the coefficient as zero (pylogit MNL model)

I read the data, the convert to dummies the product features. Then I dropped the reference terms as suggested here (https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/marketing-analytics-series-choice-based-conjoint-nguyen-u-s-cma/)

Finally, I created a basic specifications and names dictionary ad applied the model MNL of pylogit

```
original = pandas.read_csv('xlstats_cbca.csv')

original=pandas.get_dummies(original,columns=['Temperature','Sugar','Lemon','Intensity']).astype('int')

original.drop(['Temperature_temp_warm','Sugar_No sugar','Lemon_lemon_no','Intensity_intensity_low'],axis=1,inplace=True)

variable=original.iloc[:,4:].columns

basic_specification=OrderedDict()
basic_names=OrderedDict()

for col in variable:
    basic_specification[col]=[[1,2,3]] 
    basic_names[col]=[col]

model1=pl.create_choice_model(data=original,
                                    alt_id_col='AlternativeIdInSet', #column that contains ID of alternatives 
                                    obs_id_col='ChoiceSetId', #column that contains ID of choice set
                                    choice_col='Choice', #column that contains choices
                                    specification=basic_specification,
                                    model_type="MNL",
                                    names=basic_names)


model1.fit_mle(numpy.zeros(7),method="bfgs") 
model1.get_statsmodels_summary()
```

How do I correct the approach?

```
Log-likelihood at zero: -219.7225
Initial Log-likelihood: -219.7225
Estimation Time for Point Estimation: 0.00 seconds.
Final log-likelihood: -219.7225
/Users/pranavnerurkar/opt/anaconda3/envs/pymc3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py:527: RuntimeWarning: Method bfgs does not use Hessian information (hess).
  warn('Method %s does not use Hessian information (hess).' % method,
/Users/pranavnerurkar/opt/anaconda3/envs/pymc3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pylogit/base_multinomial_cm_v2.py:1228: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  self._store_inferential_results(np.sqrt(np.diag(self.cov)),
/Users/pranavnerurkar/opt/anaconda3/envs/pymc3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pylogit/base_multinomial_cm_v2.py:1259: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  self._store_inferential_results(np.sqrt(np.diag(self.robust_cov)),
Out[27]:
Multinomial Logit Model Regression Results
Dep. Variable:  Choice  No. Observations:   200
Model:  Multinomial Logit Model Df Residuals:   193
Method: MLE Df Model:   7
Date:   Mon, 17 Jul 2023    Pseudo R-squ.:  0.000
Time:   14:49:15    Pseudo R-bar-squ.:  -0.032
AIC:    453.445 Log-Likelihood: -219.722
BIC:    476.533 LL-Null:    -219.722
coef    std err z   P>|z|   [0.025  0.975]
Temperature_temp_ice    0   nan nan nan nan nan
Temperature_temp_very_warm  0   1.18e+07    0   1.000   -2.31e+07   2.31e+07
Sugar_1 sugar   0   nan nan nan nan nan
Sugar_2 sugar   0   nan nan nan nan nan
Lemon_lemon_yes 0   nan nan nan nan nan
Intensity_intensity_Medium  0   6.85e+06    0   1.000   -1.34e+07   1.34e+07
Intensity_intensity_strong  0   3.69e+07    0   1.000   -7.24e+07   7.24e+07
```

Comment: @timothyb0912- can u guide plz